# In SQL, how to check which rows are affected by the IN clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For this question, I will use this imaginary data:

```
Table Name: Person

PersonID(PK),PersonName,PersonAge
1,Jack,0
2,Joe,0
3,Jennifer,0
4,Jacky,0
5,John,0
```

When I run this query:

```
UPDATE Person
SET PersonAge = 50
WHERE PersonName IN ("Jennifer", "Peter")
```

SQL will respond to me saying:

```
1 row affected
```

And it will change the age of Jennifer to 50 and will do nothing with Peter because he does not exist in the Person table.

My question that I have is:

Is it possible for SQL, in this specific situation, to not just tell me that 1 row is affected, but also which row? Would it be possible for SQL to tell me that we just changed Jennifer?

I have tried to find a solution for this but mostly found topics regarding the number of rows affected rather than the actual data. I am running SQL Server Management Studio and SQL version 15.x)

Comment: *"SQL will respond to me saying: `1 row affected`"* I'd expect it to return saying *"`Invalid column name 'Peter'. Invalid column name 'Jennifer'.`"*

Comment: As for the question, have you considered the `OUTPUT` clause?

Comment: Never store age, Jennifer will become 51 next year, and your table data will be out-of-date. Store DOB instead.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Just to demonstrate that the statement you have would fail: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p5W2bwk7)

Comment: @ThomA that would be fine *if* the OP happens to have `quoted_identifier` [off](https://dbfiddle.uk/eH4MLbP1)

Comment: I made a typo in OP and used " instead of '. It will not fail using ' see:
https://dbfiddle.uk/pQWGegII

Comment: True, but *why* would they do that, @Stu . Microsoft have "threatened" to remove the functionality in a future version of SQL Server.

Comment: @ThomA This is true but I've encountered more than a few databases, some pretty old, where this was the case eg where a lot of dynamic sql was built using double quoted strings

Answer (score 0):

Try OUTPUT statement:

```
UPDATE Person
SET PersonAge = 50
OUTPUT inserted.PersonName
WHERE PersonName IN ('Jennifer', 'Peter');
```

Answer (score -1):

Some database systems provide extensions or additional features that allow you to get more details about the affected rows. For example: In SQL Server, you can use the OUTPUT clause to return the columns of the rows that were affected by the UPDATE statement. Example:

```sql
DECLARE @UpdatedRows TABLE (PersonID INT, PersonName VARCHAR(255), PersonAge INT);

UPDATE Person
SET PersonAge = 50
OUTPUT INSERTED.PersonID, INSERTED.PersonName, INSERTED.PersonAge INTO @UpdatedRows
WHERE PersonName IN ('Jennifer', 'Peter');

SELECT * FROM @UpdatedRows;
```